# cassandra 1.1.1 default cql version

Tags: cassandra, cql

Do someone know if it is possible to set in Cassandra (1.1.1) configuration CQL3 as default for connections?
I know that you can set it in cqlsh with --cql3, or in java Cassandra client, but that is not what I need. The problem is that it cannot be set in java clients and I want to avoid messing in their code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  In this case java clients simply need to add support for this.  For JDBC the issue to watch is http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/issues/detail?id=38

Answer (score 1):

Having an issue with java client failure-to-insert (w/o any error message), I followed the link provided by jbellis, and discovered that adding "?version=3.0.0" to the connection url will get things working again, as in:

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://my_server_addr:9160/my_keyspace?version=3.0.0");

...tried that, and problem was immediately solved.